# text hover effect with popup in wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, text, hover

Inside a page in wordpress, I would like when the user hover over a word (text), then it show a popup with some text that give more details about the word they just hovering on.

How to do that and I can't found any plugin to do that, I think Java script/ jquery can do, but don't know how to do that.

Already try some samples by put the HTML and Jquery script inside the HTML of that page, but not working for some reason,

Also, I know I need to put the below statement in the html header, but no idea where to do in wordlpress? in the theme header.php? or index.php for my wordpress theme.

Could anyone help by give me more details how can i make that happen.

It same effect like when you mouse hover over to the tag of this post, it popup a message box with content.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how complex a popup you're looking for you might want to try using jquery tootip: http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Placing your jquery script and or links to .js files should be done in your header.php file as well provided the theme you are using is setup in that manner. You'll know if you see similar links to other .js files in the file that you're in the right place.

Comment: Hi, that is good enough, but how can i attached to the page from that source code?

Comment: @user1985788 You should be able to just pop the script into the header and then simply use the title tag in an href as follows <a href="yourlink" title="your title">Your Tooltip</a>